# Gnuplot nested do loop and plotting on the same graph

Tags: gnuplot

Hi I'm using gnuplot to create a large number of graphs. To save myself work I've written a script that tries to plot all possible graphs.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset
is_missing(x)=system("./ismissing.sh ".x)
set terminal post eps enhanced color
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set grid
models="Cebeci-Smith Baldwin-Lomax Spalart-Allmaras Launder-Sharma Chien"
files="./CebeciOut/ ./BaldwinOut/ ./SpalartOut/ ./LaunderOut/ ./ChienOut/"
xgrid="35000 70000 140000 280000 560000"

# Plot grid convergence Spalart
do for [f=1:words(files)]{
    set output sprintf('%s%s',word(files,f),'ZPGGridConvergence.eps')
    set title sprintf("%s%s",word(models,f), " ZPG Grid Convergence")
    set xlabel "N_y"
    set ylabel "C_f Final"
    print f
    do for [i=1:words(xgrid)]{
        filename=sprintf("%s%s%s%s",word(files,f),'yconv_',word(xgrid,i),"x")
        if(is_missing(filename)==0){
            plot filename using 1:2 title sprintf("%s%s",word(xgrid,i), " X Gridpoints") with linespoints
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have a problem, after one full iteration the script fails, ie f is never made 2 despite the first plots completing successfully. The error given is

```
cannot open file; output not changed
line 25: util.c: No such file or directory
```

which I haven't managed to decipher. Any help would be much appreciated. Also is there a way to use replot in this loop given I haven't already created a plot.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"files" are actually dirs in your code.

If you want to place the output in a subdir, then make sure that it exists and is writable.

gnuplot cannot create subdirs automatically. You can add `system("mkdir -p ".word(files,f))` ( on linux/unix) in your code to create the directory if needed.